# Producing map images for Wikipedia?

Tags: python, rendering, perl

I would like to make several map images (e.g. SVG or PNG) like [those on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBlank_maps) but in not popular projection. I am interested in scripting solution.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWorld98.svg) I found this note:

```
Generation Notes
perl xml2svg.pl -P12 --proj=cylindrical_equidistant:0,0.793353340291235 -x8000 world98
```

*(I haven't found this script yet. Where is it?)*

Also I found mentions of Generic Mapping Tools and Mapnik.

There are also several other flavors of maps on Wikipedia. I believe, more ways to create a map images exist.

So what are preferred map rendering techniques and datasets for Wikipedia?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, you want to make Thematic Mapping with python and svg. you can find very good tutorial here about [How to Make a US County Thematic Map Using Free Tools](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/).

[image: .]

Comment: Sorry, my question is more about creating svg map, not just colorizing existent. Though I will do use similar technique later on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're interested in [Kartograph.py](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/). You could use it from command line or as a python module.

OpenStreetMap should be a good data source for wikipedia maps as well as [Natural Earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) or open data portals.

Comment: Thanks! It was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately it seems to be abandoned for a while. I could not solve this [issue](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/issues/62). Also, shapely(http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) is not fast for my purposes and it produced strange results (I gave up, as i am not very experienced in GIS and Python). [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) really looks more fast and stable. I am learning it now. In the question I tried to ask about popular and convenient libraries/programs for images intended to be used on Wikipedia (Best practices)